# Meteor App doesn't work on my computer

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

we have been trying to develop a meteor for our project but recently I have been getting an error of which I was not able to make any sense at all. The bizarre things is that the same app works smoothly on other computers with no problems whatsoever. 
Other meteor apps work without any problems.

I was wondering whether node caches anything from previous versions of my project ?

However when I run the project I get this error ;

```
W20160508-18:10:03.070(2)? (STDERR) /Users/user/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1b51q9m++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
W20160508-18:10:03.070(2)? (STDERR)                         throw(ex);
W20160508-18:10:03.070(2)? (STDERR)                               ^
W20160508-18:10:03.180(2)? (STDERR) TypeError: Cannot read property 'accessToken' of undefined
W20160508-18:10:03.181(2)? (STDERR)     at AccountsServer._onCreateUserHook (server/accounts.js:12:43)
W20160508-18:10:03.181(2)? (STDERR)     at AccountsServer.Ap.insertUserDoc (accounts_server.js:1230:21)
W20160508-18:10:03.181(2)? (STDERR)     at createUser (password_server.js:980:25)
W20160508-18:10:03.181(2)? (STDERR)     at AccountsServer.Accounts.createUser (password_server.js:1049:10)
W20160508-18:10:03.181(2)? (STDERR)     at _createUser (server/modules/generate-accounts.js:40:12)
W20160508-18:10:03.181(2)? (STDERR)     at _createUsers (server/modules/generate-accounts.js:30:7)
W20160508-18:10:03.181(2)? (STDERR)     at Object.generateAccounts (server/modules/generate-accounts.js:14:5)
W20160508-18:10:03.182(2)? (STDERR)     at _generateAccounts (server/modules/startup.js:11:46)
W20160508-18:10:03.182(2)? (STDERR)     at Object.startup (server/modules/startup.js:4:3)
W20160508-18:10:03.182(2)? (STDERR)     at server/startup.js:1:38
```

Comment: Close terminal and try again.

Comment: I have tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried `meteor reset`?